# This JavaScript implementation of range is fast. What are it's downsides?

Tags: javascript, optimization

This implementation of range() is very fast:

```
RANGE = []; for (var i=0; i<65536; ++i) RANGE.push(i-32768);
range = function(a,b){ return RANGE.slice(a+32768,b+32768); };
```

Are there downsides in using this approach?

Comment: Why are you subtracting `32k`?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas To allow for negative ranges

Comment: @Dokkat: It might be more intuitive to run the loop from `-32k` to `+32k`

Answer (score 2):

relatively speaking-

1) its a bit heavy on the memory use, requiring the memory for a property + mem of a number for each integer in the possible range

2) always consumes the memory and cpu needed to intialize, even if the script never has use for it.

Comment: Interesting. 2 can be solved initializing the array only after the first use of range(); this would aggravate 1, though.

Comment: I don't think lazy loading it would have any significant effect on #1.

Comment: +1. Lazy loading would just make the first invocation of `range` slower than the average implementation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Range could be declared as an [Arraybuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#6), which supports both method slice and an arrayview of just a part of the buffer without copying the data. Returning an arrayview would mitigate the problem of memory consumption and using typed array would use ~128k memory instead of 512k.

Also the function could possibly be self-modifying doing the initialization at the first call.

```
range = function(a,b) {  initialize_range;
        range = function(a,b) { return RANGE.slice(a,b) };
        return RANGE.slice(a,b); }
```